# Material-ui component onKeyUp event is not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, onkeyup

I have a material-ui component Grid and I have a onKeyUp event on that
But somehow `onKeyUp` is not triggering

```
<Grid item xs={12} onKeyUp={handleClickOnKeyUp} sx={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick= 
  {handleClickGrid}>
</Grid>
```

and the functions are

```
const handleClickOnKeyUp = () => {
  console.log("123123123");
}

const handleClickGrid = () => {
   console.log("456456456");
}
```

Other code for Grid and Grid items under Grid container is working fine, There is no problem in that
The `onClick` event is also working but `onKeyUp` is not working
What is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `tabIndex` to the component (element) to allow it to accept focus.  For example:

```
<Grid
  item
  xs={12}
  onKeyUp={handleClickOnKeyUp}
  sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
  onClick={handleClickGrid}
  tabIndex={0} {/* tabIndex added here */}
>
...
</Grid>
```

**Updated answer to additional comment:**

If you'd also like to remove the focus outline, you can add the styling:

```
<Grid
  item
  xs={12}
  onKeyUp={handleClickOnKeyUp}
  sx={{ cursor: "pointer", "&:focus": { outline: "none" } }} {/* removes focus outline */}
  onClick={handleClickGrid}
  tabIndex={0}
>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-leaf-x4e6xv?file=/demo.js

***Note:** If you are concerned about accessibility, I'd be careful setting that `tabIndex` property to anything other than zero (`0`).*

Comment: Thank you so much !! But it is inserting the border in grid

Comment: @SrushtiShah I've updated my answer and CodeSandbox with the styling to remove the focus outline.